# How to test cxf generated SOAP client?

Tags: java, apache, testing, soap, cxf

I have generated classes from a wsdl using wsdl2java from CXF. This wsdl has securitypolicy which uses security token though.

Could someone guide me how to test this client? I am stuck as the client tries to obtain a token from a mock server I built using WireMock, but it cannot as the mock server does not know how to respond.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try generating server side classes using cxf and implement the server side method to respond with proper response.

Again this is kind of simulator which you build using cxf.

Comment: I don't have any idea about how the server is implemented. I just want to mock a response in xml from server. The issue with cxf generated stub is that it would expect a response from the server with a security token.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my post again.
So there is no straightforward way of doing this as it is very difficult to mock a server with the security policies implemented.

Thus, what I did is create another service without the authentication part and tested it. We can also say that we don't need to test the authentication part as cxf anyways handles it.